# CXF: how to access to the generated SOAP request

Tags: cxf

We have a Web Service client generated with CXF from a WSDL.
We now need to have an access to the generated SOAP requests in order to persist them.
It seems that the framework does not provide this behaviour by default.

Anyway do you guys ever tried to do such a thing?

I am thinking of building my own interceptor that can access to the fully generated message but maybe there is a better choice?

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default CXF uses stax to stream your requests. If you add an interceptor, you can get access to the stax output writer and copy the events.

There is existing code in CXF to force the existence of a DOM tree; see code related to SAAJ and security.

In general, detailed CXF questions get better answers on the CXF user mailing list than here.

Comment: ok I think I will go for the interceptor solution. I was thinking of binding it just before the StaxOutEndingInterceptor that flushes the Stax stream. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: I strongly recommend a message to the mailing list, or even just a google of the mailing list archive. I'm not experienced this particular end of things.

Comment: Ok no problem, i'll check with the mailing list. Thanks ;)